# Gradle git dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I write multi module android projects. One of this module - it is another project in git repository on gitlab.
How i can pull it in gradle? I tried gradle-plugin-git-dependencies and maven-git-commit-id-plugin/pull/92

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
classpath 'org.batcha.gradle.plugins:git-dependencies:0.1'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/bat-cha/gradle-plugin-git-dependencies/0.1/git-dependencies.gradle'
compile('org.batcha:dummy-project-a:4.2').ext.git = 'https://gitlab.com/Artem_Chekharin/uz.git'
}
}
```

But they didn't pull project from git. I use Android Studio 0.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run **initGitDependencies** gradle's task first.